# How to validate the non-clickability of an UI Object in robot framework?

Tags: automated-testing, robotframework

I have to validate an UI object that is not-clickable. In UIautomator, for that element clickable is False. So I want validate that in script. Please give me idea for the same.

Comment: What sort of object are you asking about? A native UI element, an element on a web page, something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) from the BuiltIn library to run another keyword and see if it succeeds or not without failing the test case itself.

> Runs the given keyword with given arguments and returns the status as a Boolean value. This keyword returns Boolean `True` if the keyword that is executed succeeds and `False` if it fails. This is useful, for example, in combination with Run Keyword If. If you are interested in the error message or return value, use Run Keyword And Ignore Error instead. (...)
>   Errors caused by invalid syntax, timeouts, or fatal exceptions are not caught by this keyword. Otherwise this keyword itself never fails.

A possible example would be:

```robot
*** Keywords ***       
Element Should Not Be Clickable
    [Arguments]   ${element}
    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Click Element    ${element}
    Run Keyword If    'True'=='${status}'    Fail    "Element should not be clickable"
```